# Q: Alternative to Clock.schedule_interval in Kivy

Tags: python, multiprocessing, kivy

I have a separate process parallel to my Kivy app and I am checking a status of shared multiprocessing value using Clock.schedule_interval.

```
# call the method every second
Clock.schedule_interval(self.callback_status, 1)
```

When the main thread in Kivy is busy doing something else e.g. a loop or showing a popup, the checking is interrupted. Is there an alternative to Clock.schedule_interval? Can Kivy manage a background process without queues, pipes or else?

p.s. A minimalistic working example would still be too much so for a taste is just the callback method:

```
@mainthread
def callback_status(self, dt):
    global v
    try:
        if v.value == 1:
            # do something
        else:
            # do something else
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

################### UPDATE N.1 ######################

As suggested I run a thread for checking the shared value. I have to comment out `@mainthread` for `def pin_check(self)` otherwise the main thread remains blocked in the infinite loop not allowing the graphical part to perform its tasks. This approach works well till there are no other threads executed simultaneously. Then the checking is interrupted.

```
@mainthread
def callback_status(self, dt):
    # run the checking in a thread
    t = threading.Thread(target = self.pin_check)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()

# @mainthread   # if left uncommented it blocks the main thread
def pin_check(self):
    # checking the shared multiprocess value
    global v    # shared value  
    try:
        while True:
            if v.value == 1:
                try:
                    self.alert()
                except Exception as e:
                    print("error 1", e) 
                break
            else:
                pass
    except Exception as e2:
        print("error 2", e)
        pass

@mainthread
def alert(self):
    print("do something here")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a kivy application that has 2 multiprocessing.Process scripts that both handle their own task. An example is my script for reading an RFID-card:

```
import evdev
from evdev import InputDevice, categorize, ecodes  
import multiprocessing

class RFID(multiprocessing.Process):
    '''
    This class handles the communication with the RFID-scanner and puts every scan in a queue.
    This queue can be consumed anywhere in the application.
    '''
    def __init__(self, rfid_queue, configuration):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.configuration = configuration
        self.inputdevice = self.configuration.get_value('RFID', 'inputdevice')
        self.device = InputDevice(self.inputdevice)     # Calling the InputDevice the RFID-scanner is connected to
        self.rfid_queue = rfid_queue                    # Calling the queue from the constructor
        # Normal ASCII lookup table (without caps)
        self.scancodes = {
            0: None, 1: u'ESC', 2: u'1', 3: u'2', 4: u'3', 5: u'4', 6: u'5', 7: u'6', 8: u'7', 9: u'8',
            10: u'9', 11: u'0', 12: u'-', 13: u'=', 14: u'BKSP', 15: u'TAB', 16: u'q', 17: u'w', 18: u'e', 19: u'r',
            20: u't', 21: u'y', 22: u'u', 23: u'i', 24: u'o', 25: u'p', 26: u'[', 27: u']', 28: u'CRLF', 29: u'LCTRL',
            30: u'a', 31: u's', 32: u'd', 33: u'f', 34: u'g', 35: u'h', 36: u'j', 37: u'k', 38: u'l', 39: u';',
            40: u'"', 41: u'`', 42: u'LSHFT', 43: u'\\', 44: u'z', 45: u'x', 46: u'c', 47: u'v', 48: u'b', 49: u'n',
            50: u'm', 51: u',', 52: u'.', 53: u'/', 54: u'RSHFT', 56: u'LALT', 57: u' ', 100: u'RALT'
        }
        # Caps ASCII lookup table
        self.capscodes = {
            0: None, 1: u'ESC', 2: u'!', 3: u'@', 4: u'#', 5: u'$', 6: u'%', 7: u'^', 8: u'&', 9: u'*',
            10: u'(', 11: u')', 12: u'_', 13: u'+', 14: u'BKSP', 15: u'TAB', 16: u'Q', 17: u'W', 18: u'E', 19: u'R',
            20: u'T', 21: u'Y', 22: u'U', 23: u'I', 24: u'O', 25: u'P', 26: u'{', 27: u'}', 28: u'CRLF', 29: u'LCTRL',
            30: u'A', 31: u'S', 32: u'D', 33: u'F', 34: u'G', 35: u'H', 36: u'J', 37: u'K', 38: u'L', 39: u':',
            40: u'\'', 41: u'~', 42: u'LSHFT', 43: u'|', 44: u'Z', 45: u'X', 46: u'C', 47: u'V', 48: u'B', 49: u'N',
            50: u'M', 51: u'<', 52: u'>', 53: u'?', 54: u'RSHFT', 56: u'LALT',  57: u' ', 100: u'RALT'
        }
        self.resultstring = ''                          # Empty String
        self.capsLock = False                           # Caps check for the ASCII lookup table
        self.device.grab()                              # Reserve the device for exclusive access

    def run(self):
        for event in self.device.read_loop():
            if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY:
                data = categorize(event)  # Save the event to inspect it later
                # ------------------ Capslock check ------------------
                if data.scancode == 42:
                    if data.keystate == 1:
                        self.capsLock = True
                    if data.keystate == 0:
                        self.capsLock = False
                # ------------------ Capslock check ------------------

                # ------------------ Decode and add to empty resultstring ------------------

                if data.keystate == 1:  # Down events only
                    # if the scanned item is in capslock, get data from the capslock lookup table
                    if self.capsLock:
                        key_lookup = u'{}'.format(self.capscodes.get(data.scancode)) or u'UNKNOWN:[{}]'.format(data.scancode)  # Lookup or return UNKNOWN:XX
                    # if the scanned item is not in capslock, get data from the normal lookup table
                    else:
                        key_lookup = u'{}'.format(self.scancodes.get(data.scancode)) or u'UNKNOWN:[{}]'.format(data.scancode)  # Lookup or return UNKNOWN:XX
                    # check if data is not an LSHFT (left shift) OR CRLF (linebreak)
                    if data.scancode != 42 and data.scancode != 28:
                        # add the key that has been looked up from the lookup table to the resultstring
                        self.resultstring += key_lookup  
                    if data.scancode == 28:
                        # if there's a linebreak, add the resultstring to the queue.
                        self.rfid_queue.put(self.resultstring)
                        # empty the resultstring for the next RFID scan
                        self.resultstring = ''

                # ------------------ Decode and add to empty resultstring ------------------
```

In the mainthread I use the following to start a process using the following:

```
rfidThread = RFID(rfid_queue, configuration)
rfidThread.daemon = True
rfidThread.start()
```

using a consumer function I pop scanned RFID-cards from the queue in my mainthread like so:

```
def check_rfid_scan(self, scannedRFID):
    with Database(self.databasepath) as db:
        data = db.return_all_from_table('USERS')
        uids = db.return_known_UIDs('USERS')
        uids = ['.'.join(i) for i in uids]
        if scannedRFID in uids and self.rfidqueue is False:
            index = uids.index(scannedRFID)
            uid, user, permission = data[index]
            self.rfidqueue = True
            if permission == 1:
                self.popup = AdminPopup()
                self.popup.value.text = str(user + f' ({self.permissionCheck(permission)})')
                print(f'Popup geopend: {self.popup.value.text}')
                self.popup.bind(on_dismiss = self.dismissPopupEvent)
                self.popup.open()
            elif permission == 2:
                self.popup = ManagerPopup()
                self.popup.value.text = str(user + f' ({self.permissionCheck(permission)})')
                print(f'Popup geopend: {self.popup.value.text}')
                self.popup.bind(on_dismiss = self.dismissPopupEvent)
                self.popup.open()
            elif permission == 3:
                self.popup = UserPopup()
                self.popup.value.text = str(user + f' ({self.permissionCheck(permission)})')
                print(f'Popup geopend: {self.popup.value.text}')
                self.popup.bind(on_dismiss = self.dismissPopupEvent)
                self.popup.open()
        else:
            if self.invalid is False and self.rfidqueue is False:
                self.invalid = True
                self.invalidpopup = RFIDInvalidPopup()
                print('Invalid popup geopend')
                self.invalidpopup.bind(on_dismiss = self.dismissInvalidPopupEvent)
                self.invalidpopup.open()
```

This consumer function gets initialized using:

```
Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.checkRFIDQueue(), 0.5)
```

I open a popup, check the permission of the user in the database and open a popup according to the permission. So my main means of interacting with the main thread is using queues between the process and the python application. It does use schedule_interval, but I find this the best solution for MY problem. I don't know if you can use this, but if it helped give me an upvote :)

EDIT: only just noticed this was a question from last year, but will keep this posted.

Answer (score 0):

> When the main thread in Kivy is busy doing something else e.g. a loop or showing a popup, the checking is interrupted. Is there an alternative to Clock.schedule_interval?

Normally best practice would be to do the opposite, *don't* block the main loop and instead do any long-running work in a thread.

You could also do the work from your question in a thread, but if it isn't a long-running operation I'd be more inclined to keep it in the main thread and fix whatever is blocking your clock.

> Can Kivy manage a background process without queues, pipes or else?

This doesn't really have anything to do with Kivy, you can use whatever threading and subprocessing you like with all the normal advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: I would say that the clock is blocked by two threads executed in "parallel": an open popup and reading/writing to a serial port. Both these two threads are executed in the main thread. This is a feature of my app and this parallel thing happens quite often. Anyway if understood correctly I should put the callback_status in a thread or subprocess instead?

Comment: "Both these two threads are executed in the main thread." <- this doesn't make sense, either they're threads or they aren't. Note that thread here is a technical term, code running in a thread will not in general block the app's main loop.

Comment: And I still think that you should probably put anything that blocks the main thread into its own thread.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Yes they are threads and  are executed in the main-loop.

Comment: That still doesn't make sense. The main loop takes place in one thread, usually called the main thread. If your other loops are running in threads, we wouldn't normally say they are executing in the main loop, they are simply running in different threads simultaneously (to the extent allowed by the GIL).

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to explain and I am glad this is finally sorted out. So if I use your words @inclement, in my app there are often different threads running simultaneously with the main thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230944/discussion-between-parovelb-and-inclement).